# How do I install Oracle Java JDK 8 on Freya?

Tags: software-installation

How can I install JDK 8? Is it possible to install it from PPA?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can install it from PPA :

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Or download it from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) then move `jdk-8*` to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.x` then run these commands:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.x/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.x/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.x/bin/javaws" 1
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/java
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javac
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javaws
```

`x` in `1.8.x` means the latest version of JDK 8

Comment: Why do you need the `python-software-properties` package?

Comment: Can not comment to previous answer: "Why do you need the python-software-properties package? – codehitman " You need it in case you get following error: add-apt-repository: command not found You might also need:
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: Why python-software-properties?