# Android Studio Error: Could not determine Java version

Tags: release-freya, android

After installing Android Studio, I started getting this error: 
`Error: Could not determine Java version.` upon gradle sync. I do have Java JDK7 installed, OpenJDK, and OpenJSE installed. How can I fix this?

Comment: did you set the `JAVA_HOME` environment?

Comment: I used apt-get to install JDK as instructed [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get)

Comment: please run `echo $JAVA_HOME` in your terminal. Do you get a valid path to your Java binaries?

Comment: No I don't.. Strange... Let me do that real quick

Comment: Did me no good. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Damn... to be honest, your question doesn't sound like it's elementary OS specific... superuser.com should be the proper place for it.

Comment: Have you installed the Oracle jdk?

Comment: I did install Oracle JDK as said above. I know it's not eOS specific but i felt that it was in the right place as I've not run into this bug elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/716/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-8-on-freya/717#717) for how to installing JDK on your elementary OS (also it works for java 7).

Then If your problem still appears then go to `Configure -> Project defaults -> Project structure -> SDK Location` in welcome screen and add your JDK path. (Usually on `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.x.y/`)

Comment: The second part of your answer solved it! Thank you so much!